Find the smallest positive integer $n$ satisfying a condition

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ for which there exist integers
$x_{1} < x_{2} <...< x_{n}$ such that every integer from $1000$ to
$2000$ can be written as a sum of some of the integers from
$x_1,x_2,..,x_n$  without repetition.

I think the smallest $n$ is $1001$. We can choose $x_1=1000, x_2=1001,...,x_{1001}=2000$. Is my prediction right? If yes, could someone help me prove that is the smallest $n$ satifying? Thanks in advance!

Do you mean  a number never repeats, or doesn't repeat in any particular number being formed  ?

I think the answer is $11$. We can take $1=2^0,2^1,\ldots,2^{10}=1024$ and the base-$2$ representation of each of those numbers from $1000$ to $2000$ is unique. I don't know how to prove that this is minimal, though.

@trueblueanil yes, for example it can't happen like this $1000=x_1+x_5+x_1+...$

Could anyone prove $n\neq 10$? I could prove $n\geq 10$.

Obviously $n\le9$ cannot happen because in that case the different possible summations could span at most $2^9=512$ different numbers, which is less than the numbers we are trying to represent, i.e., $1001$.

@Euclid yes, I'm stuck at the case $n=10$.

Hint: consider the $3^{10}$ ordered pairs of disjoint subsets of ten $x_i$. Either both sum to  $1000$, or one sums to less than $1000$, or their union sums to more than $1000$

I think the answer should be 63.
Let's assume, $x_1+x_2+x_3+...=2000$
the summation of first $n$th number is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2000$
or, $n\approx 63$
$2000=(1+2+...+63)-16$
or, $2000=(1+2+...+15)+(17+18+...+63)$
so, $63$ is the lowest value and we can get $2000$ without repeating any number. But can we get a smaller number? Let's take a random number $1000$. Again calculate summation from $1$ to n. $1000=(1+2+...+45)-35$ or, $1000=(1+2+...+34)+(36+37+...+45)$
Following this method, we can bring out any number within 2000.
